# Python - Regex to Get directory name from HDFS

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to extract a folder name from the result of a subprocess command. The result is 
Found 1 items

```
drwxr-xr-x   - user user          0 2017-05-04 17:19 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170406204755
```

I want to extract `lib_20170406204755` . I was able to do it using

```
process = subprocess.check_output(['hdfs','dfs','-ls','/user/oozie/share/lib'])
print process.split(' ')[-1].rstrip().split('/')[-1]
```

The folder is always `lib_timestamp`

How can do this using regex?

Comment: You at least should provide the expected structure of the folders. Is the name always the same if not, what parts change and how. Ej: Folder always starts with lib_+isodate.

Comment: yes the naming convention is always `lib_timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

No regex required here, you may as well use `split()`:

```
string = "drwxr-xr-x   - user user          0 2017-05-04 17:19 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170406204755"

folder = string.split('/')[-1]
print(folder)
# lib_20170406204755
```

But if you insist:

```
[^/]+$
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = "drwxr-xr-x   - user user          0 2017-05-04 17:19 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170406204755"

rx = re.compile(r'[^/]+$')
folder = rx.search(string).group(0)
print(folder)
# lib_20170406204755
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/P9j98G/1).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`(?!/)(lib_\d*)`

This regex is searching for for something that starts with `lib_` followed by a bunch of numbers, should be enough if no similar folders are found on the result.

`(?!/)` is just to make sure that the folder is preceded by a `/`

[Example](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F!%2F)(lib_%5Cd*)&test_string=drwxr-xr-x%20-%20user%20user%200%202017-05-04%2017%3A19%20%2Fuser%2Foozie%2Fshare%2Flib%2Flib_20170406204755&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach would be to use the `os.path` module to pick apart paths.

```
import os
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['hdfs','dfs','-ls','/user/oozie/share/lib'])

# there are 8 columns in the output, i.e. we need a maximum of 7 splits per line
output_table = [line.split(maxsplit=7) for line in output.splitlines()]

# we are interested in the basename of that path
filenames = [os.path.basename(row[7]) for row in output_table]
```

with this test input:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - user user          0 2017-05-04 17:19 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170406204755
drwxr-xr-x   - user user          0 2017-05-04 17:19 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20110523212454
```

filenames will be `['lib_20170406204755', 'lib_20110523212454']`